# Как делается такая менюшка как вконтакте

Tags: html, javascript, css

Вот [тут](http://vk.com/developers.php) сверху горизонтальная менюшка

Как она сделана что цвет текста при наползании слоя на слой меняется в том месте где наползло, а где не наползло остается по старому

(анимация не интересует, интересует именно как это сделано, на основе чего css?)

Вот картинка, обведено красным

[image]

**Вот так не должно быть**

(тут смена цвета шрифта происходит только после анимации)

[image]

Comment: Да-да. Тоже интересно узнать.

Comment: Оказывается - это сделано на PHP.

Comment: Анимация на пхп? Может покажете как? Я что-то себе это плохо представляю.

Comment: А можно ссылку, где появляется это меню? Никак не могу найти.

Comment: в первом предложении вверху ссылка дана

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Да в общем ничего сложного. Если схеметически описать, то это примерно так:

```
$('selector').click(function(){
    $('blok_with_blue_bg').animate({
        left: position_of_active_element
    }, function(){
        // это callback-функция, которая выполняется после завершения анимации
        $('active_element').css('color','new_color');
    });
});
```

P.S. Чтоб было более понятно, я набросал вам [простенький пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/QdGdx/)

---

**UPD**
Может не на все 100% так же, как на ВК, но на 95% так точно. [Смотрите то, что получилось](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/CgfVx/). Сделал анимацию помедленней, чтоб вам опять не пришлось скрины делать ))

Comment: А вот и нет =)

У тебя смена цвета шрифта происходит после анимации

А вопрос то бы совсем другим

Вконтакте смена цвета шрифта происходит не после анимации, а в том месте где слой анимации перекрывает слои менюшек

Чтобы понять нужно щелкать PrintScreen и смотреть во время анимации

Вот и спрашиваю как они так сделали?

сверху добавил картинку

Comment: Зачем делать printscreen. Поменяйте задержку на скажем 2000 и увидите все в более замедленном исполнении.

Comment: Lucky, PrintScreen проще

Comment: Ну да. Попробуйте еще на видео снять. Потом в замедленной съемке смотреть.

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj, дополнил в своем ответе.

Comment: Думал в html уже придумали при наложении слоя заменять цвет шрифта

А оказывается это все тоже старое колесище

Вот так наглядней http://jsfiddle.net/RNs25/

Comment: > Думал в html уже придумали при наложении слоя заменять цвет шрифта

@dfhsfhgfj, а зачем? Задача очень специфическая, поэтому не уверен, что разработчики определят её как актуальную и будут ставить в список первоочередных задач.